# Can't Select any Items of a <Dropdown /> with a Keyboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I've got the following Dropdown in my [Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/) app

```
 <Dropdown text='Filter' icon='filter'>
    <Dropdown.Menu>
      <Dropdown.Item>Important</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item>Announcement</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item>Discussion</Dropdown.Item>
    </Dropdown.Menu>
 </Dropdown>
```

When I use the Tab key to select the Dropdown, the Menu opens but I cannot focus on or select any options via the keyboard. Selecting tab again closes the menu and moves onto the next focusable element on the DOM

Strangely, using the `options` configuration allows me to access any option via the keyboard (which appears to render the same html in the browser)

```
const options = [
  { key: 1, text: 'Choice 1', value: 1 },
  { key: 2, text: 'Choice 2', value: 2 },
  { key: 3, text: 'Choice 3', value: 3 },
]

const DropdownExampleClearable = () => (
  <Dropdown options={options} selection />
)
```

So far I've tried a combination of `tabIndex` and manually calling the `focus` method, but absolutely nothing is working. I know accessibility [wasn't taken into consideration](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/3745) when this framework was built, but this is a bit silly.

Anyone run into this issue before?

I'm running `semantic-ui-react v2.0.1` & `semantic-ui-css v2.4.1`

Comment: They have some [demos](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/). They seem to confirm what you're experiencing, that keyboard interaction doesn't work with menus built using `Dropdown.Menu`.

Comment: @Ouroborus it's super strange. Reading through the source code for `<Dropdown />` but it's difficult to follow. I've even tried placing a button within the menu, nothing. It seems no element within the Menu can be focused on

Comment: Looking at the [issues](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues), it seems there were a lot of tickets submitted for issues closely related to this one in 2016, 2017. I wonder if they just never got around to fixing it. Submitting a new issue might stir up new interest or at least point you to a newer existing issue for it.